# How to get started on WSO2 CDM?

Tags: wso2-iot

I have downloaded and started the Milestone 3 version of WSO2 CDM. How do you bring up the relevant CDM application UI from the Management Console?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 CDM milestone 3 does not have a UI application withit. CDM is a  framework which provides core functionaliies for managing any device type. For example WSO2 MDM solution has specific plugins, connectors and a UI to manage mobile devices. Hence you need to write your own plugins, connectors and a UI bundle on top of CDM framework to make a use of it.